# htaccess from www to non-www bringing variable in session/cookie

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cookies, session-variables

.htacces redirects from `www.example.com` to `example.com` (same domain without www.)
Returning visitor could have in user-agent a  `visitor_id` cookie.
I want to bring this value through domains within a cookie or session.
I tried this, but the cookie is created for the www domain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} visitor_id=([^;]+)
RewriteRule .* - [C,env=foo:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com [L,R=301]
Header set Set-Cookie "visitor_id=%{foo}e; path=/" env=foo
```

Moreover the environment variable works on localhost (Apache 2.4.2, Win32), but online (Apache 2.2.25, linux) the value in cookie is `"%{foo}e"` instead of expected number.

Also tried with `mod_session_cookie` but can't find practical examples.

How redirect through domains, bringing `visitor_id` in a cookie or session cookie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, the environment `%{env}` variables are not behaving consistently across different Apache versions, I suggest setting the *cookie* with a `RewriteRule` itself using the `[CO]` *cookie* flag.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} visitor_id=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* $0/vid/%1 [C] # Appends the cookie value to the URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)/vid/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,CO=visitor_id:$2:.example.com:14400:/]
```

Here are the list of changes made to your `.htaccess` file:

- `RewriteCond` matches are case-insensitive now (using `[NC]`)
- The dots in `%{HTTP_HOST}` condition have been escaped `\.` ( `.` matches any char otherwise)
- The first `RewriteRule` appends the visitor id (captured as `%1`) to the URL (captured as `$0`)
- The last `RewriteRule` parses the visitor id from the URL (as `$1`) and performs a permanent `[R=301]` redirect to `http://example.com` along with writing a cookie named `visitor_id` using the `[CO]` flag.

The syntax of the *cookie* rewrite flag is as follows

```
[CO=NAME:VALUE:DOMAIN:lifetime:path:secure:httponly]
```

where specifying values for *name*, *value* and *domain* is mandatory. The *lifetime* defaults to `0` which means the cookie persists for the current browser session only. *Path* defaults to `/`, *secure* and *httponly* to `false`.

The `[CO]` flag used specifies *domain* as `.example.com` so that the *cookie* becomes accessible to all the hosts under `example.com` domain. The *lifetime* is specified as `14400` which is in minutes and so amounts to `10` days.

Comment: Excellent solution. The only improvement could be `RewriteRule ^(.*)/vid/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,CO=visitor_id:$2:.example.com:14400:/]` that redirects every path, not only to top level.

Comment: @Salvador Thanks. That does improve the rule a lot. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can be applied on **domains** and **subdomains**.

If you do not set the domain cookie attribute, by default, the cookie domain will be the full host name used., So actually a user targeting `http://www.example.com` gets a cookie with domain www.example.com, and after redirection on `example.com` this cookie is not valid anymore.

But if the cookie sent by your application, on both example.com or www.example.com contains:

```
# Watchout there is a dot in front of the domain
# required for old browsers to match subdomains
domain=.example.com;
```

Then this cookie would be valid for both `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` (and in fact for any subdomin also). The client would manage it automatically, without any complex stuff in apache configuration.

Instead the stuff is in the **application responsible for the visitor_id cookie generation**, if it's a PHP application this is defined by default in the  in the [cookie_domain](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) setting, but it can also be enforced on [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) function usage. Of course such settings are also available for Java EE or .Net applications, in all web application you can have some control on the cookie domains.

This could be used for a simple SSO mechanism or to track visitors between subdomains like in your case, and it's a very robust solution.

Comment: Studying the subject I came the same conclusion: was enough to create a super-cookie in www.example.com, e.g. with php `setcookie("visitor_id", $id, time()+864000, "/", ".example.com");` which makes unnecessary all this .htaccess cooking.